# How to query the roster using JSJAC XMPP client

Tags: xmpp

How can I query full roster using JSJAC XMPP client? I have tried following function for this, but it does not work:

```
function getRoster(con){
    var roster = new JSJaCIQ();
    roster.setIQ(null, 'get', 'roster_1');
    roster.setQuery(NS_ROSTER);
    con.send(roster);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of con.send, try:

```
con.sendIQ(roster, {result_handler: function(aIq, arg) {
    var node = aIq.getQuery()
    // do something with roster
  });
```

You need to have a callback that fires when the roster is returned.  To be complete, set a error_handler as well, in case an IQ error is returned or you time out.

Comment: I have just changed the line:

roster.setIQ(null, 'get', 'roster_1');

with

roster.setIQ(con.domain, 'get', 'roster_1');

and it works now. I already have a IQhandler for processing the response.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for commenting on such old question, hoewever this pops as #1 result in google on 'JSJAC roster' and the above answers didn't worked for me. i don't know whether something changed in the JSJaC API, however i was receiving iq errors 'service-unavaliable'. i had to use this code instead:

```
var rosterRequest = new JSJaCIQ();
rosterRequest.setType('get');
rosterRequest.setQuery(NS_ROSTER);
connection.send(rosterRequest);
```

(so no domain setting and no id setting - just the type, and namespace).